# Definition of concavity

Tags: functions

The mathematical definition of a function being concave between points $x_1$ and $x_2$ is the following:

$\lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)f(x_2) \leq f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)$, for any $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$.

Can someone give a detailed, intuitive explanation of this theorem?

Comment: Another definition, that I think is more intuitive or fundamental, is that a function is convex iff its epigraph is convex.  This explains why the word "convex", already used to describe sets, is also used to describe functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the two points $(x_1, f(x_1))$ and $(x_2, f(x_2))$.  The function $f$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is no lower than the line segment connecting these two points.  For example, $\lambda=0.5$ corresponds to the halfway point.  The LHS corresponds to the midpoint of the line segment, the RHS corresponds to the function evaluated at the average of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Note: you have a typo in your statement, it should begin $\lambda f(x_1)$ not $\lambda(x_1)$.

Comment: I misspoke -- I meant concave, so I will change the question to that.

Comment: But that doesn't change the answer, except to put the function below the line instead of above it.  Do you need further explanation?

Comment: @BettyMock No further explanation needed; thanks.